# What to do when jQuery() is not defined, but $() works fine

Tags: jquery

I am having trouble with Laravel and including jQuery in it the right way. I have it in package.json as one of the dependencies, and **$()** works fine from the console, but if I try **jQuery()**, it gives me error, as if it wasn't included. Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: What does `$().jquery` give you in the console?

Comment: Are you sure the `$` is referring to jQuery and not some other library? For `$()` to work, `jQuery()` should too - unless you've re-assigned the variable after defining the library, although I imagine that would create a whole other set of issues. Could you show an example of your code, and how you include the jQuery library in the page

Comment: Try adding `var jQuery = $`?

Comment: @apsillers it gives me Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'jquery' of undefined

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I am using Laravel's new way of including assets with nodejs and npm. In package.json, one of the dependencies is "jquery": "^3.1.0". $ works fine in the console, it works as expected, my $(document).ready works fine, but the included DataTables.js is using jQuery() and that breaks.

Comment: @ivanacorovic Hmm, is this the version with Webpack? I believe you should check bootstrap.js where it binds jQuery to the window. I think it is only binded to window.$.

Comment: @Win yes, it is a version with Webpack and I don't understand at what moment exactly the jQuery gets included. I have commented out require ('./bootstrap') from my app.js because it creates this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'csrfToken' of undefined. Could that be it? Because bootstrap.js has this: window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');

Comment: @Win I have followed https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/vue/vuejs-error-cannot-read-property-csrftoken-of-undefined and added back bootstrap line, but still nothing changed.

Comment: @ivanacorovic Hi, I think you're getting confused in the console of Google Chrome. $ is often used within the developer panel such as when you inspect an element you can access it via $0. It seems like you have not included JQuery. Your best best is to just load it from a cdn such as Cloudflare. If you can try and $('body').hide(); does that work in console?

Comment: @Win that's how I'd usually do it, but this Laravel new way got me totally confused. $('body').hide(); works. Actually, now that I have bootstrap.js back, I've added var jQuery = $ as Vinnie suggested, right above the inclusion of the plugin that uses this jQuery(), and it works. I'm still hoping there is a better way to do it.

Comment: @ivannacorovic This is the only way I'm afraid unless you load it from a cdn or include it yourself locally. The problem with Webpack is that you're wanting to modularlise your code and jQuery really isn't even built for that, I have no idea why it's shipped default like that. Especially when Vue uses a virtual DOM, and Taylor is pushing Webpack/Vue.

Comment: @Win Thank you so much for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

I was also having similar issue with webpack. I have included jQuery library through cdn link in script instead of importing jQuery.

So, instead of just using jQuery or $, I used `window.jQuery` or `window.$` and now there's no warning message.

Alternatively, you may import jQuery or $ instead of inserting script:

```
import jQuery from 'jquery'
// now, no need to use window.jQuery
// just jQuery works fine without any warning
```